# SQL Query to GROUP BY using multiple WHERE values?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to show a simple table showing users in the database, but exclude users who returned items during a specified date range... For some reason I am stumped

```
SELECT Refunded, Product, COUNT(Amount) as Orders FROM `customer-data.all-users` WHERE Time BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-25 00:00:00' AND Refunded = 'FALSE' GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: Table structure?

Comment: Are you getting any `error` ?

Comment: What's your error?